# HP ProLiant Support Pack (PSP) creates multiple grub entries

Tags: linux, redhat, hp, kernel, hp-proliant

After installing HP's PSP 8.73 on RHEL5 with a G7 Blade, I end up with 4 grub entries

1 The Standard RHEL

2 HP (choosen as default)

3 HP hpahcisr

4 HP mptlinux

I'm confused as to why I get all these entries, does entry 2 contain 3 and 4 ?. 
If I boot from 2 will I be booting with all the HP drivers(3 and 4) and an HP kernel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fine using the default selection.

The current ProLiant Support Pack for your operating system is [version 9.00](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D4091412%257CprodNameId%253D4091432%257CswEnvOID%253D4004%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-ad77b71d9a7b4056a5e5bb5f10%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken). As for the multiple boot entries in your grub, it's a function of what you choose to install from the support pack. By default, the PSP will install EVERYTHING. `hpahcisr` and `mptlinux` are device drivers for hardware that doesn't even exist in your G7 blade server (hpahcisr is for the low-end [B110i SATA RAID controller](https://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/home/?sp4ts.oid=3958194). mptlinux is for [LSI HBA's](http://www.lsi.com/channel/products/storagecomponents/Pages/HBAs.aspx)). When those are selected, the HP installer creates an initial ramdisk and a corresponding kernel entry for each of those because they could potentially be boot controllers/devices for some systems.

I trim down the items that get installed by the ProLiant Support Pack. [A good guide to follow is the HPSUM guide here](http://communitylinux.org/node/265).

In short, I edit the bundle description file from the psp tarball. In version 9.00 of the PSP, the file is named `bp000977.xml`

Near the bottom of the XML file, I choose which items I want to install from the support pack. For most G6/G7 blades and standalone servers, the following works well. I remove the HP-provided CCISS and HPSA packages since they create unwanted ramdisks and conflict with the kernels I need to use, the HBA's, NIC drivers and fibre-channel utilities. I leave the core health and system management packages in the install manifest.

```
  <contents>
    <package install="no">kmod-cciss-4.6.28-17.rhel6u2.x86_64.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">kmod-cciss-4.6.28-17.rhel6u1.x86_64.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">kmod-cciss-4.6.28-17.rhel6u0.x86_64.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">kmod-hpahcisr-1.2.6-12.rhel6u1.x86_64.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">kmod-hpahcisr-1.2.6-12.rhel6u2.x86_64.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">kmod-hpahcisr-1.2.6-12.rhel6u0.x86_64.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">kmod-mpt2sas-10.10.17.00-1.rhel6u1.x86_64.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">kmod-hpsa-3.0.0-4.rhel6u0.x86_64.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">kmod-hpsa-3.0.0-4.rhel6u1.x86_64.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">kmod-hpsa-3.0.0-4.rhel6u2.x86_64.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">hp-e1000-8.0.25-1.src.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">hp-e1000e-1.6.2-1.src.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">hp-tg3-3.122g-2.src.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">hp-netxtreme2-7.0.36-2.src.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">hp-netxtreme2-iscsi-7.0.36-2.src.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">hp-nx_nic-4.0.579-2.src.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">hp-igb-3.2.10-3.src.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">hp-be2net-4.0.479.0-2.src.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">hp-be2iscsi-4.0.480.0-2.src.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">hp-mlnx-en-1.5.5.7-14.src.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">hp-qlcnic-5.0.17.4-3.src.rpm</package>
    <package install="yes">hp-health-9.0.0.48-44.rhel6.x86_64.rpm</package>
    <package install="yes">hp-snmp-agents-9.0.0.48-49.rhel6.x86_64.rpm</package>
    <package install="yes">hpsmh-7.0.0-24.x86_64.rpm</package>
    <package install="yes">hp-smh-templates-9.0.0.36-35.all.noarch.rpm</package>
    <package install="yes">hp-ams-1.0.0-570.rhel6.x86_64.rpm</package>
    <package install="yes">hpvca-7.0.0-12.linux.rpm</package>
    <package install="yes">cpqacuxe-9.0-24.0.noarch.rpm</package>
    <package install="yes">hpacucli-9.0-24.0.noarch.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">hp-fc-enablement-1.2-7.noarch.rpm</package>
    <package install="no">fibreutils-3.2-4.x86_64.rpm</package>
    <package install="yes">hpdiags-9.0.0-36.linux.x86_64.rpm</package>
  </contents>
```

I save the bundle file and proceed with a silent installation (`./hpsum /s`), but you should be able to run the graphical installation with this reduced package set as well.

Comment: HP PSP install ethernet drivers and others drivers included in redhat kernel, i like to have the server in clean state

Comment: @c4f4t0r You don't have to install the drivers. I only install the agents that are not in the Linux kernel.

Comment: :) ok i did that too